# mysql insert to ignore already available row in multi row insert

Tags: mysql

i am trying to insert multiple rows in mysql with one query.

if i can run several queries then there is no issue as only duplicate rows will be ignored and all new data will be inserted but it require 250 times i have to run the query so we have combined all in one query but the problem is if anyone rows are already present in table then whole new set of data are ignored and not inserted. is there any better way to solve this issue ??
this is my insert statement

```
insert ignore into tablea (id,url) values ('564','martshop-13942249521240.jpg'),('565','artshop-139422494229.jpg'),('566','artshop-139422494229.jpg'),('567','artshop-139422494229.jpg'),('568','artshop-139422494229.jpg'),('569','artshop-139422494229.jpg')
```

id is unique so if id 567 is already present ealier then the insert fails as expected but if i run each pass individually then all other row will insert but i have to run several passes. is there anyway i can ignore existing row in insert and add non existing row in database ??

Comment: Your SQL syntax is correct and should be doing what you want. I have tested it in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6872e/1/0. As you see, I insert 567 first and then I am running `insert ignore` with all your values. In the results you can see 568 and 569. Isn't this what you wanted to do? What is not working in your case?

Comment: @urban checking again what is happening at my end. will update

Comment: @urban i am using innodb